# Can I jailbreak my way out of a passcode request?

Tags: jailbreak, security

My father owns an iPad 1. He forgot his numerical access code and tried enough times that the device now reads "Connect with iTunes."

Apple assumes you sync your device frequently with a computer  but the only time I recall him doing that is when he upgraded to iOS 5. iTunes on that computer, however, says "no can do, put in the code first."

Apparently [the only way out](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1212) is to boot in recovery mode and flash the device clean, which means losing permanently access to all apps ever, backwards and forwards in time. (We have been unable to install any new app at all for a year or so.) This means being stuck with a version of Safari that, as you well know, runs out of memory and crashes and burns on most websites.

Hooray.

Can I jailbreak the device now? Would that help me get out of this situation?

Answer (score 4):

No.
You will need to restore using iTunes. The iPad will completely be factory reset (meaning like it's fresh out of the box). Your personal data on the device will be lost but you can redownload all apps for free using the same Apple ID you bought them with.

However you might run into some issues since the iPad 1 only runs iOS 5 and most apps require iOS 6 nowadays. Some might still be downloadable since Apple added a feature to support old iOS versions parallel (see http://9to5mac.com/2013/09/17/ios-app-store-now-allows-legacy-app-downloads-to-support-older-hardware-and-software/). However this will depend on the App Developer, so you might run into trouble getting some (probably a lot) of Apps back if they are not backed up to your computer.

Safari isn't an App that can be updated by itself, it comes with iOS, and the version depends on the iOS version.

Comment: FYI: it's an iPad 1 I'm talking about. It's running iOS 5. There is literally no application that can be downloaded from the App Store for it. There really wasn't personal data on that device; the apps *are* the whole problem.

Comment: True, I edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

If there is no important data on the iPad itself, perhaps an upgrade to a newer iPad is in order if you and/or your father can afford it. The iPad 1 is rapidly becoming an orphan, and will in time become an important historical icon, just like the Apple ][ and the rainbow Apple logo.

As is explained elsewhere on this page, updates to any apps previously purchased will be available in the App Store, where you must provide the original AppleID for proof of purchase.

You can trade in the iPad 1 for a $45 Apple Store gift card through Apple's [Reuse & Recycling Program.](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/reuse_and_recycle) Apple Store US has some decent deals on [refurbished iPads](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/specialdeals/ipad)  of all kinds and colours, too. If you prefer new items, the [least-expensive iPad Mini](http://store.apple.com/us/buy-ipad/ipad-mini) is $299 retail.

Comment: Why the downvote?